# Plotly: How to retrieve y axis values for a grouped bar chart from a nested dict?

Tags: python, graph, plotly

This is my final dictionary

```
{'1': {'Pen': [0.99], 'Note': [1.62]},
 '2': {'Pen': [1.94], 'Note': [2.17]}}
```

I am trying to plot group bar chart using plotly in python
I got my x value
 `[x for x in cdict.keys() for k,v in cdict.items()]`

i am unable to get y values correctly.

Comment: Please show us your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
y_pen = [cdict[j]["Pen"][0] for j in cdict]
y_note = [cdict[j]["Note"][0] for j in cdict]
```

---

**y_pen:**

```
[0.99, 1.94]
```

---

**y_note:**

```
[1.62, 2.17]
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is what you're looking for:

[image]

If that's the case, you'll have to make a list for the x values like `['Pen', 'Note']` and retrieve a list of lists for the y-values like `[[0.99, 1.94], [1.62, 2.17]]`.

**Complete code:**

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cdict = {'1': {'Pen': [0.99], 'Note': [1.62]},
         '2': {'Pen': [1.94], 'Note': [2.17]}}

# get x-values, in this case ['Pen', 'Note']
xVals = list([cdict[k].keys() for k in cdict.keys()][0])

# get y-values, in this case [[0.99, 1.94], [1.62, 2.17]]
yVals = []
for x in xVals:
    yVals.append([cdict[j][x][0] for j in cdict])

# set up plotly figure
fig=go.Figure()

# add trace for each element in yVals
for i, y in enumerate(yVals):
  fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=xVals, y=y, name = 'Group'+str(i+1)))

fig.show()
```